# Save rqt_plot settings

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to save the rqt_plot (topics plotted) configuration and launch it from launch file? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209964/save-rqt_plot-settings/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-27

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rqt_plot` command allows to pass topic names as arguments (run `rqt_plot -h` for detailed command usage). You can combine this with the `--args` attribute of the `<node>` element in roslaunch:

```
<launch>
  <node name="pos_vel_plot"
        pkg="rqt_plot"
        type="rqt_plot"
        args="/joint_states/position[0] /joint_states/position[1]" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-05-27**:
Oops, so it is easier than I thought. Thank you, it works :)

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-05-27**:
What currently cannot be done (that was possible with `rx_plot`) is to have multiple subplots in `rqt_plot`. You can somewhat emulate that behavior with multiple `rqt_plot` instances in a `rqt` canvas, but the timelines are independent, which makes synchronized pausing impossible.